# Is there a way to build hasManyTrough with belongsToMany?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

HasManyThrough works only if I build relations with hasMany, but there is belongsToMany.
I know that I can hard code and merge arrays, but want more elegant solution. 
Any ideas?

Teachers can work in many schools
Schools can have many teachers
Teachers can have many subjects

[image]

Comment: there might be something to be cleared first.. one-to-many dealt using `hasMany`, e.g. one teacher had many subject. `belongstoMany` deals with many-to-many, e.g. students had many teachers through the subjects they had. `hasManyThrough` on the other hand, is a shorthand for `hasMany` (one-to-many) accross multiple chain of models. as far as  i know, many-to-many chain need to be navigated manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I've created a package for cases like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```
class School extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Subject::class,
            ['school_teacher', Teacher::class, 'subject_teacher']
        );
    }
}

$subjects = School::find($id)->subjects;
```